# Type Error that The Layerout doesn't match in Particle Net

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, typeerror

I try to apply Particle Net on my study, but there are some problems. When I try to use the example training code provided by [this](https://github.com/hqucms/ParticleNet). And when I try to run to convert_dataset.ipynb file to convert the raw datasets, here comes an error that I don't know how to fix?

Here is the code, also available [here](https://github.com/hqucms/ParticleNet/blob/master/tf-keras/convert_dataset.ipynb):

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.bool = np.bool_
import awkward
import uproot_methods

import logging
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.DEBUG, format='[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)s: %(message)s')

def _transform(dataframe, start=0, stop=-1, jet_size=0.8):
    from collections import OrderedDict
    v = OrderedDict()

    df = dataframe.iloc[start:stop]
    def _col_list(prefix, max_particles=200):
        return ['%s_%d'%(prefix,i) for i in range(max_particles)]
    
    _px = df[_col_list('PX')].values
    _py = df[_col_list('PY')].values
    _pz = df[_col_list('PZ')].values
    _e = df[_col_list('E')].values
    
    mask = _e>0
    n_particles = np.sum(mask, axis=1)

    px = awkward.JaggedArray.fromcounts(n_particles, _px[mask])
    py = awkward.JaggedArray.fromcounts(n_particles, _py[mask])
    pz = awkward.JaggedArray.fromcounts(n_particles, _pz[mask])
    energy = awkward.JaggedArray.fromcounts(n_particles, _e[mask])

    p4 = uproot_methods.TLorentzVectorArray.from_cartesian(px, py, pz, energy)
    pt = (px**2 + py**2)**0.5

    jet_p4 = p4.sum()

    # outputs
    _label = df['is_signal_new'].values
    v['label'] = np.stack((_label, 1-_label), axis=-1)
    v['train_val_test'] = df['ttv'].values
    
    v['jet_pt'] = jet_p4.pt
    v['jet_eta'] = jet_p4.eta
    v['jet_phi'] = jet_p4.phi
    v['jet_mass'] = jet_p4.mass
    v['n_parts'] = n_particles

    v['part_px'] = px
    v['part_py'] = py
    v['part_pz'] = pz
    v['part_energy'] = energy

    v['part_pt_log'] = np.log(pt)
    v['part_ptrel'] = pt/v['jet_pt']
    v['part_logptrel'] = np.log(v['part_ptrel'])

    v['part_e_log'] = np.log(energy)
    v['part_erel'] = energy/jet_p4.energy
    v['part_logerel'] = np.log(v['part_erel'])

    v['part_raw_etarel'] = (p4.eta - v['jet_eta'])
    _jet_etasign = np.sign(v['jet_eta'])
    _jet_etasign[_jet_etasign==0] = 1
    v['part_etarel'] = v['part_raw_etarel'] * _jet_etasign

    v['part_phirel'] = p4.delta_phi(jet_p4)
    v['part_deltaR'] = np.hypot(v['part_etarel'], v['part_phirel'])

    def _make_image(var_img, rec, n_pixels = 64, img_ranges = [[-0.8, 0.8], [-0.8, 0.8]]):
        wgt = rec[var_img]
        x = rec['part_etarel']
        y = rec['part_phirel']
        img = np.zeros(shape=(len(wgt), n_pixels, n_pixels))
        for i in range(len(wgt)):
            hist2d, xedges, yedges = np.histogram2d(x[i], y[i], bins=[n_pixels, n_pixels], range=img_ranges, weights=wgt[i])
            img[i] = hist2d
        return img

#     v['img'] = _make_image('part_ptrel', v)

    return v

def convert(source, destdir, basename, step=None, limit=None):
    df = pd.read_hdf(source, key='table')
    logging.info('Total events: %s' % str(df.shape[0]))
    if limit is not None:
        df = df.iloc[0:limit]
        logging.info('Restricting to the first %s events:' % str(df.shape[0]))
    if step is None:
        step = df.shape[0]
    idx=-1
    while True:
        idx+=1
        start=idx*step
        if start>=df.shape[0]: break
        if not os.path.exists(destdir):
            os.makedirs(destdir)
        output = os.path.join(destdir, '%s_%d.awkd'%(basename, idx))
        logging.info(output)
        if os.path.exists(output):
            logging.warning('... file already exist: continue ...')
            continue
        v=_transform(df, start=start, stop=start+step)
        awkward.save(output, v, mode='x')

srcDir = 'original'
destDir = 'converted'

# conver training file
convert(os.path.join(srcDir, 'train.h5'), destdir=destDir, basename='train_file')
```

And the error occurs at the last code:

```
TypeError: __class__ assignment: 'ObjectArrayMethods' object layout differs from 'TLorentzVectorArray'.
```

Can anybody know how to use it, or you can provide another example of ParticleNet that I can really learn how to use it and carry out the example successfully?